# How to display "Message box" using MVC3 controller

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-3.0

I have been facing an issue to display "Message Box" after executing of some code in controller

for ex:-

```
public ActionResult IsLoginExsit(CustomerDO loginData)
        {

            JsonResult jsonResult = new JsonResult();            
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginData.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginData.Password))                 
             {                     
                 bool result = Businesss.Factory.BusinessFactory.GetRegistrations().IsLoginExist(loginData.UserName, loginData.Password);                     

                     jsonResult.Data = result;

             }      
             return jsonResult;
        }
```

as seen in above example, if result is true or false, then i would like to display message box stating that login is suceess or fail.

```
<!-- language: lang-.html -->
    <form class="formStyle" action="#" method="POST" id="frmAuthenticate">
            <div class="row">
            <input class="text row" type="text" value="" id="txtUserName"/>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
            <input class="text row" type="password" value="" id="txtPassword" /> 
            </div>  
            <div class="row last">
            <a class="link" href="">Forgot Password?</a>   
            <a class="button3" href="/Registration/Registration" title="Registration" >Signup</a>        
<input type="submit" class="button4" id="btnGo" value="Go" />            
            </div>
        </form>
```

If login is exist i want to navigate to "/Customer/CollaborationPortal", else i would like to display message "Authroization fail".

```
$("#btnGo").click(function (e) {
                var RegData = getRegData();
                if (RegData === null) {
                    console.log("Specify Data!");
                    return;
                }
 var json = JSON.stringify(RegData)
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Registration/IsLoginExsit',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: json,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function (data) {                     
                    if(data.result == true){                                                 
                    location.href = "/Customer/CollaborationPortal";                     
                    }                    
                     else{
                         alert("Login failed"); //or whatever                     
                     }             
                     }
                });
return false;
            });
            function getRegData() {

                var UserName = $("#txtUserName").val();
                var Password = $("#txtPassword").val();
                return { "UserName": UserName, "Password": Password };
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are missing ; after var json = JSON.stringify(RegData)
 and you did not update controller code

Comment: Hi, i have updated my controller code.

Comment: What about ; ?
If you set your result as jsonResult.Data, then in your success function you should check for if(data == true). If you used client code from my answer, then you should also have used server code.

Comment: Hi, i have changed as you suggested and also changed it by keeping the "return false;" after closing of "btnGo" click event...I have updated code...thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way do that in MVC as simple as in winforms application.

Simplest way to display message box on web page in your case is to change this action from ActionResult to JsonResult, and replace your if with:

```
return Json(new {result = result});
```

and, in web page you need to use ajax (i.e. submit a form using jquery's $.post) and in callback function check for result:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function(){
    var formData = $(this).closest("form").serialize();
    $.post("urltoyourcontrollerhere/IsLoginExsit", formData, function(data){
        if(data && data.result == true){ alert("Login exists!");}
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**
The code you posted seems OK, but there is one problem. The success function:

```
success: function (data) {
                        location.href = "/Customer/CollaborationPortal";
                    }
```

This function will always perform redirect, no matter what controller has returned. You need to check if data.result (if you returned your json as Json(new {result = result});) is true, and then redirect, else display alert. So, try:

```
success: function (data) {
                    if(data.result == true){                        
                        location.href = "/Customer/CollaborationPortal";
                    }
                    else{
                        alert("Login failed"); //or whatever
                    }
            }
```

Another thing:

```
            var RegData = getRegData();
            if (RegData === null)
```

If you want this to work, you need to return null from getRegData when one of textboxes is empty.

Comment: $(this).closest("form").serialize() is returning "", please let me know if you can address it.

Comment: Can you post html of the form/button you are clicking to run this controller action, I will update answer accordingly. $(this).closest("form") is jQuery selector for form containing button you clicked on. Your button is maybe not inside the form etc, it is the best that you copy html from browser -> view source.

Comment: I have updated answer, if you have some problem, please log/inspect data variable in success function to check what does it contain (what controller action has returned). If it does not run, then your action is not returning json, use network tab in IE dev tools or Firebug to capture network data and see what you get back from server.

Comment: Hi, I have tested with Firebug, the alert box is displaying and immediatly the page is getting loading, so i am unable to view alert box , but when i debug the code, then i am able to view alert box,if the alert box is able to view then the issue is resolved.

Comment: Did you replace your function under success in $.ajax with this from answer? If so, please update your question with code, as well with code for display of alert. That code for some reason runs on page load, like it is not specified for success of ajax but as a separate function.

Answer (score 3):

You CAN display a message box when done.

```
public ActionResult LoginExist(BAMasterCustomerDO loginData)
{
    return new JavascriptResult { Script = "alert('Saved successfully');" };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to display a message box using the server side code. You'll need to pass some data back to the view indicating the login status then write some client side code to display the message box.

Comment: Please let me know some example if you can as it is very urgent for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use a property of your view model which will be passed to the view and which will contain this information:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
bool result = Businesss.Factory.BusinessFactory.GetRegistrations().IsLoginExist(loginData.UserName, loginData.Password);
model.IsLoginSuccess = result;

... 

return View(model);
```

and inside your strongly typed view you would test the value of this property and display the message accordingly:

```
@if (Model.IsLoginSuccess)
{
    <div>The Login was successful</div>
}
```

Comment: I am not using "Model" in my project as i am creating entities in business solution. Please let me know if you can address it with some other logic

Comment: @Pardha, well, you should be using models. That's the recommended practice.