# how to show Alert messages in Asp.net MVc3 (ex: User Created Successfully)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

iam using Asp.Net 2010 and MVC3 framework..I am new to this.
When user registers in page i want show "Registered Successfully " Alert Message..
How to do this ?
So please help on this...

Comment: which coding language you are using C# or VB?

Comment: ASP.net 2010,C#,MVC3, I created All controllers,Model and views..its  working fine and Storing data in Database also.But when its saved i need show Message to User..please guide me

Comment: You can see my answer to a very similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8063345/how-to-show-alert-message-like-successfully-inserted-after-inserting-to-db-usi/8064147#8064147

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can use JsonResult in MVC3 with jquery support in code behind, referring to this link will give you more details [How to display “Message box” using MVC3 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553575/how-to-display-message-box-using-mvc3-controller)

Comment: where i have to Add this code..in controller or View(.Aspx)..Iam using MVC3

Comment: please guide me on this..iam hanged here

Comment: its unable to understand..please provide me some realtime scenario code