# How to show Alert Message like "successfully Inserted" after inserting to DB using ASp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

How to write a code for displaying the alert message: "Successfully registered", after user data is stored in database, using MVC

I am using Asp.Net MVC3, C#, Entity Model.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection) {
  ...
  TempData["notice"] = "Successfully registered";
  return RedirectToAction("Index");
  ...
}
```

Then, in your Index view, or master page, etc., you can do this:

```
<% if (TempData["notice"] != null) { %>
  <p><%= Html.Encode(TempData["notice"]) %></p>
<% } %>
```

Or, in a Razor view:

```
@if (TempData["notice"] != null) {
  <p>@TempData["notice"]</p>
}
```

Quote from MSDN (page no longer exists as of 2014, archived copy [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20111124074512/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx)):

> An action method can store data in the controller's TempDataDictionary object before it calls the controller's RedirectToAction method to invoke the next action. The TempData property value is stored in session state. Any action method that is called after the TempDataDictionary value is set can get values from the object and then process or display them. The value of TempData persists until it is read or until the session times out. Persisting TempData in this way enables scenarios such as redirection, because the values in TempData are available beyond a single request.

Answer (score 5):

The 'best' way to do this would be to set a property on a view object once the update is successful. You can then access this property in the view and inform the user accordingly.

Having said that it would be possible to trigger an alert from the controller code by doing something like this -

```
public ActionResult ActionName(PostBackData postbackdata)
{
    //your DB code
    return new JavascriptResult { Script = "alert('Successfully registered');" };
}
```

You can find further info in this question - [How to display "Message box" using MVC3 controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553575/how-to-display-message-box-using-mvc3-controller/)

Comment: How to do this...?iam using Entity Model..this is my code  public ActionResult Create()
        {
            try
            {                
                return View();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return LogException(ex); 
            }
        }

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var objmsg = new Models.motds();
                tblMessage msg = new tblMessage();            
                msg.CreatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                msg.ModifiedDate = System.DateTime.Now;//default id CreatedDate
                UpdateModel(msg);
                objmsg.AddMessage(msg);         
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {               
            }
        }

Comment: Try adding `return new JavascriptResult { Script = "alert('Successfully registered');" };` in place of `return RedirectToAction("Index");`

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd go with AJAX.

If you cannot switch to `@Ajax...` helpers, I suggest you to add a couple of properties in your model

```
public bool TriggerOnLoad { get; set; }
public string TriggerOnLoadMessage { get; set: }
```

Change your view to a strongly typed Model via

```
@using MyModel
```

Before returning the View, in case of successfull creation do something like

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.TriggerOnLoad = true;
model.TriggerOnLoadMessage = "Object successfully created!";
return View ("Add", model);
```

then in your view, add this

```
@{
   if (model.TriggerOnLoad) {
   <text>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     alert('@Model.TriggerOnLoadMessage');
   </script>
   </text>
   }
}
```

Of course inside the  tag you can choose to do anything you want, event declare a jQuery ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert('@Model.TriggerOnLoadMessage');
});
```

Please remember to reset the Model properties upon successfully alert emission.

Another nice thing about MVC is that you can actually define an EditorTemplate for all this, and then use it in your view via:

```
@Html.EditorFor (m => m.TriggerOnLoadMessage)
```

But in case you want to build up such a thing, maybe it's better to define your own C# class:

```
class ClientMessageNotification {
    public bool TriggerOnLoad { get; set; }
    public string TriggerOnLoadMessage { get; set: }
}
```

and add a `ClientMessageNotification`  property in your model. Then write EditorTemplate / DisplayTemplate for the `ClientMessageNotification` class and you're done. Nice, clean, and reusable.

Answer (score -1):

**Little Edit**

Try adding

```
return new JavascriptResult() { Script = "alert('Successfully registered');" };
```

in place of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```